# How to create a Project in Integrated Services Catalogue

Tags: ssis, project

I have successfully established a connection to Integrated Services and created a Catalog SSISDB but I cannot see how to create a Project. How do I create a Project and then a Package underneath it in the Integrated Services Catalogs section. I can create a package but it appears in the Integrated Services database in the MDSB folder.  I am trying to be able to run the package from a button on my Access Front End. I am using SSMS but when I Google "Projects" I get Visual Studio solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You do not directly create a project and then a package within the SSISDB. Instead, the deployable quantum is a file with `.ispac` extension that can be deployed through SSMS or the associated isdeploymentwizard.exe.

An ispac is a zip file with ssis packages, project parameters, [project level connection managers] and a manifest file. The ispac file is most commonly created by the build action of a Visual Studio SQL Server Data Tools project template.

Associating package execution to a button from an Access front end, will require you running a few stored procedures

```
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] 
    @package_name=N'Package.dtsx',
    @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT,
    @folder_name=N'Deployed Projects',
    @project_name=N'Integration Services Project1',
    @use32bitruntime=False,
    @reference_id=Null

-- Setting synchronized means this call will wait until the package is done
-- maybe that is what you want, maybe not
DECLARE @synchronized bit = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value]
  @execution_id
, @object_type=50
, @parameter_name=N'SYNCHRONIZED'
, @parameter_value=@synchronized

DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,
    @object_type=50,
    @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL',
    @parameter_value=@var0

EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
```

### Getting SSDT

This depends on your version of visual studio.

2005-2010, the product was called Business Intelligence Design Studio, BIDS, and was only available on licensed SQL Server media (SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2008R2).

VS 2012-2016?, this was a separate downloadable installer and allowed you to target SQL Server 2012-2016

VS 2017?-current, install happens through Visual Studio Installer -

> Select SQL Server Data Tools under Data storage and processing in the list of workloads.

### Workflow

- Visual studio - create SSIS project and make your package that does the thing.
- Create folder on SQL Server
- Deploy project (aka ispac) to SQL Server
- Navigate the SSISDB hierarchy and right click on package and choose Execute... Configure any parameters but do not click OK. Instead, click up top where the scroll thing is and there should be an option of "Script to new window" Choose that and then Cancel the UI.
  -- In the new SSMS window, those lines of SQL code should approximate what I have above but specific to your folder/project/package along with any parameters. I would propose you add in the SYNCHRONIZED section I supplied, otherwise this will be an async operation and a user will keep clicking the button and you'll have N copies of the same package running.
  -- Wire the button up in Access using the previous step's tsql

### References

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-tsql-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks Billinkc. So, it seems like I have to download and learn how to use Visual Studio to achieve this?

Comment: How did you envision creating an SSIS Package otherwise? Not being flippant, but hoofbeats make me think horses, not zebras